# How to supress Downloading progress message/warning in rmarkdown documents/shiny in r?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

On creating a `shiny app` I am getting message of Downloading Data- **Downloading file 1 of 1: `transit_cost.csv`** at the top of the app.

[image]

I have already used below chunk options but still get these messages:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

I have also tried below chunk options but they also hide plot & inputs:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, results='hide', fig.keep='all')
```

**How can I suppress all unwanted messages. Display just the input/output in a file that it is meant for ?**

This code is taken from **tidytuesday** by David Robinson: https://youtu.be/8jNQzce13SE?t=2938

**code**:

```
---
title: "transit_Shiny"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytuesdayR)
library(scales)
library(glue)
theme_set(theme_light())
library(countrycode)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidytext)
```

```
tt <- tt_load("2021-01-05")
transit_cost <- tt$transit_cost %>%
  filter(!is.na(e)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(start_year, end_year, real_cost), as.numeric) %>%
  mutate(country_code = ifelse(country == "UK", "GB", country),
         country = countrycode(country_code, "iso2c", "country.name"),
         tunnel_per = tunnel / length,
         rr = ifelse(rr, "Railroad", "Not Railroad"),
         station_density = stations / length) %>%
  mutate(country = fct_infreq(country))
```

Most expensive line Projects in terms of Cost/km:

```
metrics <- c("Cost / KM (millions USD)" = "cost_km_millions",
             "Length (KM)" = "length",
             "Stations / KM" = "station_density")



inputPanel(
  selectizeInput("country", label = "Country:",
                 choices = levels(transit_cost$country), selected = "India"),
  
  selectInput("metric", label = "Metric:", choices = metrics, selected = metrics[1]),
  
  sliderInput("num_lines", label = "# of lines to display:",
              min = 1, max = 30, value = 16, step = 1)
)



transit_cost_country <- reactive({
  transit_cost %>% 
    filter(country == input$country)
})




renderPlotly({
  metric <- input$metric
  
  x_axis_lab <- names(metrics)[metrics == metric]
  
  g <- transit_cost_country() %>% 
    arrange(desc(!!sym(metric))) %>% 
    head(input$num_lines) %>% 
    mutate(line = reorder_within(line, !!sym(metric), city)) %>% 
    
    ggplot(aes(!!sym(metric), line, fill = city)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_y_reordered() +
    labs(x = x_axis_lab,
         y = "",
         color = "City")
   
  if (metric %in% c("cost_km_millions")) {
    g <- g + scale_x_continuous(labels = dollar)
  }
  
  ggplotly(g)

  })
```

Comment: You set *global* options. Make a chunk containing only the code which performs the download and set the option `results='hide'` to this chunk.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent for suggesting this. This worked well !!